# Handling desktop position, font and other win32 console parameters

Tags: windows, winapi, console

Is it possible to programmatically set such windows console parameters as its left-top desktop position, console font, fast insert and selection by mouse options, etc.?

Unfortunately we can set some console parameters by invoking undocumented Windows API. For example: `SetConsoleFont`, `GetConsoleFontInfo`, `GetNumberOfConsoleFonts` from `KERNEL32.DLL`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to reposition the console you need to update the underlying HWND.  You can use the GetConsoleWindow() function to get a handle to the HWND.  From there you can call GetWindowInfo, SetWindowINfo and the like to update it's postition and size

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683175(VS.85).aspx

**EDIT** The below is actually for updating the buffer.

I believe you are looking for the SetConsoleWindowInfo function.  This will allow you to control positioning of the Console Window.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686125(VS.85).aspx

Comment: No. SetConsoleWindowInfo function manages character cells numebr of displayable window in console screen buffer. I need handling the position (in pixels) of console window in Windows desktop.

Comment: It's great!(using GetConsoleWindow() to obtain HWND). But what do you think about font and other console parameters?